# What are the RESX File Requirements for Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, resx

I've noticed that by default to string values are already in the `AppResources.resx` file within a Windows Phone 8 project, and they are `ResourceLanguage` and `ResourceFlowDirection` which are preset to `en-US` and `LeftToRight` respectively (my app is made in the default en-US culture). My question is, is it required to have these two strings in each resx file for each translated language with their respective `ResourceLanguage` and `ResourceFlowDirection` as well, or is it sufficient to have it only in the default resx file? To note, I am currently only translating into another `LeftToRight` language, but I may do a `RightToLeft` language in the future. What are the requirements for each?

Answer (score 0):

For each added culture in the project properties, default resx string values will be added for each culture specifically within its resx file. Reference http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2013/02/01/tips-for-localizing-windows-phone-8-xaml-apps-part1.aspx for information

It states:

Adding a Supported Culture from the Project Properties in Visual Studio will cause a new resource file with locale-specific name and app language initialization parameters in place to be created.